# Directory TreeView in Delphi FMX

Tags: delphi, treeview, firemonkey

I made a directory TreeView in Delphi FMX, but when I expand `'C:\Windows\WinSxS'` it contains 15000 folders. It took a lot of time, but it doesn't expand. On the other hand, when I tried to do it with a VCL TreeView, it worked fine, as it should. Is there any way to make it fast?

Here is my code:

```pascal
function SlashSep(const Path, S: String): String;
begin
  {$IF DEFINED(CLR)}
  if Path[Length(Path)] <> '\' then
  {$ELSE}
  if AnsiLastChar(Path)^ <> '\' then
  {$ENDIF}
    Result := Path + '\' + S
  else
    Result := Path + S;
end;

procedure GetDir(const ParentDirectory: string; ParentItem: TTreeViewItem);
var
  Status: Integer;
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  Node: TTreeViewItem;
begin
  Status := FindFirst(SlashSep(ParentDirectory, '*.*'), faDirectory, SearchRec);
  try
    while Status = 0 do
    begin
      if (SearchRec.Attr and faDirectory = faDirectory) then
      begin
        if (SearchRec.Name <> '.') and (SearchRec.Name <> '..') then
        begin
          Node := AddChild(ParentItem,ExtractFileName(SearchRec.Name));
          Node.HasChildren := True;
        end;
      end;
      Status := FindNext(SearchRec);
    end;
  finally
    FindClose(SearchRec);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ItemOnExpanding(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeViewItem);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Node.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    TreeView1.RemoveObject(Node.Items[i]);
  Node.BeginUpdate;
  GetDir(GetPathItem(node),node);
  Node.EndUpdate;
end;
```

It's expanding from here:

```pascal
procedure TCustomTreeView.ItemExpanded(const Item: TTreeViewItem);
var
  I: Integer;
  Child: TTreeViewItem;
  AllowExpansion: Boolean;
begin
  InvalidateGlobalList;
  if Item.IsExpanded then
    for I := 0 to Item.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Child := Item.Items[I];
      if not Child.IsInflated then
        Child.Inflate;
    end;
  RealignContent;
//end;
  if Assigned(FOnExpanding) then
    if Item.IsExpanded then
      FOnExpanding(Self, Item, AllowExpansion)
  else
    if Assigned(FOnCollapsing) then
      if not Item.IsExpanded then
        FOnCollapsing(Self, Item, AllowExpansion)
end;
```

Comment: You don't need `SlashSep()` at all, just use `SysUtils.IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter()` or `IOUtils.TPath.Combine()` instead. You also don't need `ExtractFileName()` at all. And the `RemoveObject()` loop should be between the `(Begin|End)Update` calls (and you need to add a `try/finally` for them)

Comment: it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Usually BeginUpdate/EndUpdate the Treeview and not a node. Not sure if it makes a difference (do not have Delphi handy atm).

Comment: @Brian I have already done it but no result.

Comment: @AkA "*it didn't solve the problem*" - I didn't say it would.  They were just observations, not solutions, hence posted as a comment, not an answer. You are just going to have to profile your code to see where it is actually spending all of its time to see why it is so slow.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  I edited my code to make you see where it's expanding. Please help me I have been trying to get rid of it for long time